# Discrete Choice Models

Tags: panel-data, multinomial-distribution, logit, discrete-data

For multinomial (or mixed) logit models, when the choice set is too large, either strategic sampling or random sampling of the choice set can be used. My question is: Is that also true for panel data with fixed effects?